# Updating resource in REST, send the data back to the server

Tags: java, json, rest

Hi i have created simple REST architecture using Jersey and Tomcat. I sent data from server (as a resource using "/get") to client and then customer makes some computation on this data. My problem is, how to send this calculated data from client to server ( i suppose that i have to use PUT (update resource) but i don't know how, it simply doesn't work..) ?

OK, i write something like this ( server, contains resource)

```
@Path("/resource/{id}")
public class SimplyHello {

@GET    
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject sayJSONHello(@PathParam("id")String id) {
    JSONArray numbers = new JSONArray();

    int [] myNumbers = new int [1000];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i <1000 ; i++)
        myNumbers[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; ++i) 
     numbers.put(myNumbers[i]);     

    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    try {
        result.put("numbers", numbers);
    } catch (JSONException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                       
    return result;              
}
```

Client( I perform certain operations on data)

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());     

   String jsonString = service.path("rest").path("resource").path("1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    JSONArray array = obj.optJSONArray("numbers");

    if (array == null) { /*...*/ }

    int[] numbers = new int[array.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
        numbers[i] = array.optInt(i);
    }       

     int sum=0;

      for (int i =0 ; i <array.length() ; i++)
      {
          sum= numbers[i]+sum;                   
      }
```

My problem is: how to send back this calculated data to server? I need to compare both times: from moment send data to receive data, and time calculation without sendind data. This would be simply distributed programming based on the REST services. One master and 3 slaves.
I would be grateful if someone helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the calculated object back into JSON, and then use a POST or PUT to send it back to the server.  Within the POST, you will have to read the posted JSON object - you can make it part of the request parameters.  Once you've read the posted JSON object from the client, you can de-serialize it back into the data that you need to persist.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so convert sum (score) to JSON looks like :

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
      JSONObject score = new JSONObject();
      score.put("id", sum);

      try {
            result.put("id", sum);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now i have a problem. How it send back to server because i don't know how to use PUT..  I learned with many tutorial, but i didn't find something like this..